# Android Application does not display activity

Tags: android

I created a project using view binding, but no activity is displayed. I thought at first that something was indented, but Layout Inspector shows that the application is empty

P.S. Initially, everything worked, but after some actions with the design, everything broke down. I tried to clean the Gradle cache and created a new project with the same Activity code, but it doesn't help

`OnBoardingActivity.kt`:

```kotlin
class OnBoardingStep : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_onboarding_step) {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentOnboardingStepBinding

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding = FragmentOnboardingStepBinding.bind(view)

        val titleRes = arguments?.getInt(TITLE)!!
        val desctiptionRes = arguments?.getInt(DESC)!!

        with(binding) {
            title.setText(titleRes)
            description.setText(desctiptionRes)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        const val TITLE = "title"
        const val DESC = "desc"
    }
}

class OnBoardingActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val binding by viewBinding(ActivityOnboardingBinding::inflate)

    inner class Step(
        val action: () -> Unit = ::navigateNext,
        @StringRes val actionText: Int = R.string.action_settings,
        @DrawableRes val actionDrawable: Int = R.drawable.ic_arrow_12,
        val createFragment: () -> Fragment
    )

    private val steps = mutableListOf<Step>()

    private fun initSteps() {
        val dottedSteps = listOf(
            bundleOf(
                OnBoardingStep.TITLE to R.string.app_name,
                OnBoardingStep.DESC to R.string.next
            ),
            bundleOf(
                OnBoardingStep.TITLE to R.string.next,
                OnBoardingStep.DESC to R.string.app_name
            ),
        )

        dottedSteps.forEach {
            steps += Step {
                OnBoardingStep().apply {
                    arguments = it
                }
            }
        }
    }

    inner class PagerAdapter : FragmentStateAdapter(this) {
        override fun getItemCount(): Int = steps.size
        override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment = steps[position].createFragment()
    }

    private fun navigateNext() = with(binding.pager) {
        if (currentItem + 1 == adapter?.itemCount)
            finish()
        else setCurrentItem(currentItem + 1, true)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        initSteps()

        with(binding) {
            shapePageIndicator.setCustomViewPagerAdapter(ViewPageAdapter(pager))
            pager.adapter = PagerAdapter()
            pager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
                override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                    val step = steps[position]
                    nextButton.setOnClickListener { step.action() }
                    nextButton.setText(step.actionText)
                    nextButton.setEndDrawable(step.actionDrawable)
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() = with(binding.pager) {
        if (currentItem > 0)
            currentItem -= 1
        else super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

just in case, the code of the `viewBinding` function:

```kotlin
inline fun <VB : ViewBinding> Activity.viewBinding(crossinline inflater: (LayoutInflater) -> VB) =
        lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) { inflater(layoutInflater) }
```

`activity_onboarding.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ru.driics.playm8.ui.components.viewpager.indicator.StretchPageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/shapePageIndicator"
        style="@style/Widget.DS.PageIndicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:ds_activeIndicatorColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:ds_indicatorColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nextButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/shapePageIndicator" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:text="Stop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: "Initially, everything worked, but after some actions with the design, everything broke down." - You might want to explain what these actions were, as they seem key to your issue. One things I notice is that you're overriding `onCreate` that takes `PersistableBundle` - you probably want the regular version that takes a `Bundle`.

Comment: @dominicoder I tried to use basic Bottom Sheet (FrameLayout) in an XML layout. As for the Bundle, I doubt that this is the problem, since the method was like this initially

Comment: You may doubt it, but did you verify? Because [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle,%20android.os.PersistableBundle)) indicates this version of onCreate is only called if you have an uncommon manifest attribute set.